# NativeScript - Can static XML/JS/CSS be encrypted in the distributable device specific files

Tags: android, nativescript

When I build an APK file using NativeScript build tools (`tns build android`) , it bundles all the XML/JS/CSS/images and other static files into the APK file in simple plain/text format. This way anyone will be able to easily use this code and create copy of my app. Is there any way to encrypt these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NativeScript team member here. We are currently researching how to encrypt the application JavaScript code and have some working prototypes for both iOS and Android. I would suggest to keep an eye on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/252).

Answer (score 0):

This guy has a solution  [here](http://nativescript.tools/product/4). However, there is very little documentation on how it is implemented and it has not recieved any code review. It's also $350 and I personally would trust something official from the NS team.

Your best bet right now until a runtime encryption/decryption solution can be solved is to use obfuscation and minification techniques. I use [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) for this and other projects of mine. Your xml and css will be in 'cleartext' but all the logic behind your application will be harder to reverse engineer then to do nothing with your javascript code.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: cool! appreciate the down vote. its not like i see this all the time on the site yet steer clear of downvotes. what a joke, i  hardly see how you're helping out here, and this type of cherry-picking hardly creates an environment for new comers to SO to offer help to the community.